# Bootstrap img-responsive class - Images overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows containing 3 images each.  I am using the Bootstrap grid system.  My problem is, is that the images on the second row run into the images in the top row.  Here is my markup:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I apologize if this question has already been answered.  I'm a total newb, hoping not to be a newb for long.  Thank you!

**UPD**. I want to have the two rows separated so there's a thin space between them.

Comment: Can you provide html code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your CSS looks good. Please add your HTML too.

Comment: I'm not seeing overlapping http://codeply.com/go/FOYmyQ1pKJ.. but there is no space between the rows. Is that what you mean by "overalapping"?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear.  I want to have the two rows separated so there's a thin space between them. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can add the `margin-top` property to your images. It makes a space between rows.
2. The `.img-responsive` class has defined in the [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css). So you don't need to copy all its properties. Just add the new ones.

For example:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG, it worked, it worked!!!  Thank you SO much.  Oh my word, I thought I was going to lose my mind.  Thank you a thousand times for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert when it comes to html, but wouldn't an easy solution be to just add some breaks under the first row?

It would look something like this...

```
<div class="row">
     //your columns
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="row">
    //your columns
</div>
```

Update: Now that I see your html I see that you are missing the second row.  Try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">"<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/red-eye-photography/p6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
</div>
```